# Formatted dates in a Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a spreadsheet with simple formatted dates when a form is submitted, but all dates, including the timestamp keep getting posted as "Dec 31 1969 2:00PM"... What am I doing wrong? ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Set the status of a new ticket to 'New'.

  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("New");

  var ticketTime = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Timestamp")).getValue();

  var subdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ticketTime), "GMT-10", "EEE MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Timestamp")).setValue(subdate);

  var sDate = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Start Date")).getValue();
  var strtdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sDate), "GMT-10", "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Start Date")).setValue(strtdate);

  var sTime = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Start Time")).getValue();
  var strttime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sTime), "GMT-10", "h:mm");
  //sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Start Time")).setValue(strttime);

  var eDate = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("End Date")).getValue();
  var enddate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(eDate), "GMT-10", "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("End Date")).setValue(enddate);

  var eTime = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("End Time")).getValue();
  var endtime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(eTime), "GMT-10", "h:mm");
  //sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("End Time")).setValue(endtime);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the 'dates' in your spreadsheet are not date objects, they are just strings and JavaScript evaluate it as 0, that's why you get a date value of the 'origin' (aka epoch) minus GMT offset...depending on how these values comes in the cells there might be different solutions to this. Can you show example data an tell how they were created?

To check if my guess is right you could simply try to change the display format of the 'date' cells using the spreadsheet interface.If you can change it there and get coherent results then I'm wrong... if not ... well I guess I'm right :-)

Comment: Dates in spreadsheets can be treated as js Date objects. The problem is when date objects are set to a spreadsheet the object is treated according to the documents standard formatting for dates. We need a way to sett the documents standard date formatting.

Comment: Sorry but what you say is simply wrong. When a script reads a date in a sheet, the way this date is shown in the spreadsheet is completely irrelevant... I'd suggest you try things before making such assertions

Comment: Im not sure I understand correctly what you mean then..
This code works for me:

var lastDate = sheet.setActiveCell("B1").getValue();

And gives a full js date.

Comment: What I simply say is that in a spreadsheet dates can be shown with many different formats( day+month, day+month+year, hours +min...) and that doesn't change its date object nature : Javascript will always read a date object, complete with years and months etc to milliseconds  if (and only if) it is a date and not a string representation of a date.

Comment: Okay that I agree with. I thought this guy wanted to set the formatting in the spreadsheet just like me. I have upvoted you so please remove your down votes from my other post as it is indeed correct.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest review this:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=es#formatDate(Date,String,String)

And the format patterns are these:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

And one example to help you

Utilities.formatDate(thisFile.getLastUpdated(),"GMT-5", "yyyy/MM/dd, HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 1):

This code takes date of first row which carries "Timestamp", i.e. the `new Date ("TimeStamp")` so it's getting back the wrong date as getRowIndex return 1:

```js
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  //try to increment row as below to get row 2
  row++;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  //increment last row to write to new row to observe new date
  lastRow++;
  // Set the status of a new ticket to 'New'.

  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("New");

  var ticketTime = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Timestamp")).getValue();

  var subdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ticketTime), "GMT-10", "EEE MM/dd/yyyy 'at'   h:mm a");
  //use log window select views-> logs to see your output
  Logger.log("subdate : "+subdate);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Timestamp")).setValue(subdate);

  var sDate = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Start Date")).getValue();
  var strtdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sDate), "GMT-10", "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Start Date")).setValue(strtdate);

  var sTime = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Start Time")).getValue();
  var strttime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sTime), "GMT-10", "h:mm");
  //sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Start Time")).setValue(strttime);

  var eDate = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("End Date")).getValue();
  var enddate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(eDate), "GMT-10", "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("End Date")).setValue(enddate);

  var eTime = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("End Time")).getValue();
  var endtime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(eTime), "GMT-10", "h:mm");
  //sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("End Time")).setValue(endtime);
}

//enter code here
```